# Cannot access WAMP over internet

Tags: networking, php, localhost, wamp, phpmyadmin

I have installed WAMP 3.2 on Windows Server.
I need to access the phpmyadmin running on localhost of wamp over the internet from anywhere.
After googling things, i found the modifications in httpd-vhosts.conf file this,

My httpd-vhosts.conf looks like,

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However i have setup the port no to 8080. On Server if i type localhost:8080/phpmyadmin it works.
but if i type the "IP ADDRESS":8080/phpmyadmin it gives an error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12 Server at "myIP" Port 8080

I have checked my firewall in case of blocking of any incoming connections, but its clear on firewall level.

Can anyone guide me resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is different than your Ethernet IP-Address.  Services are often configured to listen on localhost when connections are only expected from same computer. It's a security measure. Before changing it, you would want to ensure the service is sufficiently hardened to resist attacks from LAN, and/or Internet. WAMP is generally deployed as a development platform. For instance, it is configured to provide developer PHP errors and warnings that are helpful during development, but should never be shown to end-users (potential attackers). If your remote access requirement is so you can develop on WAMP remotely, then recommend setting up remote VPN access to the site, and accessing the Windows Server using Remote Desktop (through the VPN connection). Exposing a default WAMP installation to the Internet (or even a busy LAN having transient laptops/smartphones) is likely to result in a compromised server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am already logging into windows server using Remote Desktop.
I have developed few apis in PHP and Mysql, now i want to execute those apis on my windows server from anyover ( clients)  over the internet.
That is what the ultimate goal i am trying to achieve.

Comment: It's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites  Though, I would add, if you make WAMP visible to the world, it will be attacked 7x24. If you consider the cost of your time to harden WAMP, continuously monitor, and promptly mitigate new threats, you're far better off copying your app to a web hosting account.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
Besides to play safe what can u suggest more?. I have created Apis in PHP and MySQL and i have Windows dedicated server.

Comment: Continue to do development with WAMP. Get a web hosting account. Linux CPanel shared hosting. Why Linux? While you can find Windows hosting, it's not as common, may cost more due to licensing, and really, you won't miss it.  Once you've handed over management of Apache, PHP, mySQL, etc. to hosting company, you're left with a file-system: use something like WinSCP to move files from WAMP to web host; and the same myphpadmin web console you're familiar with. Any other settings (even file-system browsing) is available using the CPanel web GUI. Also, avoid EIG  (search eig research as a hobby).